# Internal Direct Product Sums

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $\Bbb Z$, let $H$ = $<5>$ and $K$ = $<7>$. Prove that $\Bbb Z = HK$. Does $\Bbb Z = H × K$?

Firstly, what is the difference between $HK$ and $H × K$? I think for both I have to show that there exists some linear combination of the two numbers such that they will span all of $\Bbb Z$, is that correct?

Comment: $H\times K$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$, as I interpret it. It's generated by $(5, 0)$ and $(0, 7)$.

Comment: I think that the most common notation writes $H K = \{h k \,:\, \text{$h \in H$ and $k \in K$}\}$.  This may or may not be a group (it is always so if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a common Abelian group).  There is a natural map from the (set or group) product $H \times K$ to the set $H K$, which may not be a homomorphism (even if $H K$ is known to be a group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "some linear combination of the two numbers such that they will span all of $\Bbb Z$" doesn't really mean anything. Perhaps you want to write "show every number is a linear combination of five and seven," that would be appropriate.

The notation $HK$ means $\{hk:h\in H,k\in K\}$. When we say $H\times K$ is an *internal* direct product, we are not only defining it to be $HK$, we are furthermore claiming every element of it is expressible in the form $hk$ ($h\in H,k\in K$) *uniquely*. The notation $HK$ does not imply any such uniqueness condition. (Also, the notation $H\times K$, interpreted as internal direct product, further implies that elements of $H$ commute with elements of $K$ and vice-versa, which $HK$ does not imply.)

An *external* direct product $A\times B$ is comprised of 2-tuples of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\in A,b\in B$; it is a *construction* out of two given groups $A$ and $B$, which do not have to have any relationship to each other (they aren't necessarily subgroups of a common group, for example). We are not talking about this construction in this problem.

(It really is unfortunate we are using multiplicative notations for an additive group...) To do the first part of the problem, you need to demonstrate that given any integer $n$ there is a way to write it as a linear combination $n=5a+7b$ for some integers $a,b$. It's enough to show this for $n=1$, do you see why? Next to see if $\Bbb Z$ is an internal direct product of $H$ and $K$, you need to figure out if every element of the form $5a+7b$ can be written that way for a *unique* pair of $a,b$; it will *not* be an internal direct product if you can say that $5a+7b=5c+7d$ but $(a,b)\ne(c,d)$ for some $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Why is it enough to show it just for the case that n=1? I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that the gcd of 5 and 7 is equal to 1...

Comment: @EmaLee The fact that gcd(5,7)=1 is *related* to the fact that it's *possible* to show it for n=1, but it's not *why* it's enough to show it for n=1. Suppose we have $1=5a+7b$ for some $a,b$. What can we do to both sides of the equation to get it in the form $n=5c+7d$ for some $c,d$?

Comment: Okay, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

$H\times K$ is the Cartesian product of $H$ and $K$.  In other words,
$$H\times K=\{(n,m):n\in H,m\in K\}.$$

You are correct as far as showing $\Bbb Z=HK$.

Comment: There is a technical difference between internal direct product and external direct product, even though they are isomorphic. The problem is speaking internally, but the Cartesian product is an external construction.

Comment: Well put. That get's right to the heart of it.

Comment: @whacka, it had better be more than that, because elements of $\mathbb Z$ *aren't* 2-tuples (well, depending on the foundations of your set theory), whereas $\mathbb Z$ *is* (canonically isomorphic to) $H \times K$.  :-)

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $5\Bbb Z\times 7\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @whacka Yes, of course. Good point.

Comment: So is the Cartesian product a type of internal direct product?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: When is $H \times K$ isomorphic to $HK$?

Comment: @Pacman If $HK$ is a group then it's isomorphic to the external direct product $H\times K$ if and only if (i) all elements of $H$ commute with all elements of $K$ and vice-versa and (ii) $H\cap K=\{e\}$. But $HK$ is not usually itself closed under the group operations.

Comment: When $xy=yx$ for all $x\in H,y\in K$, and $H\cap K=\{e\}$,  $e$ being the identity element.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: What do you mean $HK$ is not usually itself closed under the group operations?

Comment: @Pacman Not unless one of the subgroups is contained in the normalizer of the other.

Comment: But $HK$ was initially a group. Shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: I don't see that $HK$ was initially a group in the OP's question.  However the point is moot since everything is abelian.

Comment: You said "if HK is a group then its isomorphic to the ext. direct product..."

Comment: @Pacman actually whacka said that and you need to read the entire comment.

Comment: @Pacman Take any nonabelian group $G$ and pick two distinct proper subgroups $H$ and $K$ of it. Chances are, the subset $HK:=\{hk:h\in H,k\in K\}$ will not be closed under the group operation in $G$, or closed under inverses, so it will not be a group.

Comment: ok. i see. thanks. material gets intricate at times.